# Private BlockChain - Cons?

Tags: contract-development, private-blockchain, oracles, uport, poa

Plan to implement private chain based on PoA to overcome transaction speed and privacy issue. 
Q1. what is the expected TPS? any advice to increase it?
Q2. Understand that we can still leverage tools and other modules such as geth/web3/whisper, but how about ethereum ecosystems, such as uport, oracles, etc

Comment: Hi there. Just to check: a private _Ethereum_ chain based on PoA? Or are you just talking about blockchains in general? (I know you mention Geth et al... )

Comment: The question is about private Ethereum based on PoA. Could you comment  fruther?

Comment: It sounds like you've selected a solution before understanding the problem. If you don't know what the expected TPS is, then what are the reasons for choosing PoA as a solution to transaction speed? (I realise there's a difference between transaction _throughput_ and individual transacion _speed_, but I would have thought that assessing one would give an understanding of the other.) Secondly, what are you considering the privacy advantages of PoA over a private chain using PoW?

Comment: you are right- I do not have enough knowledge on blockchain yet- still learning. The reason why I mentioned PoA was coming from my assumption that public ethererum generates only 12transaction/sec due to PoW. So thought we can have more transactions by applying PoA. you sounded PoA is nothing to do with increasing # of transaction. Is that a case ? anyway to increase it with private chain. my second question was compatibility with all ecosystems- can you comment on that?